# Probability problem of win a game

Tags: probability

I have this problem about probability:

> If in a bingo, the probability for each game to win a prize is 0.2,
>   and in each game, a single prize is drawn.
>
> What is the probability that a person has to win 3 prizes, if he
>   participates in four draws?

My development was:

1. In each game i have a $\frac{1}{5}$ of probability to win a prize.
2. I have four ways to win, that are: $WWWL, WWLW, WLWW, LWWW;$ Where $L =$ lose and $W =$ Win

So i have:

WWWL: $(\frac{1}{5}*\frac{1}{5}*\frac{1}{5}*\frac{4}{5})$

And the same of the others, so finally i have a probabilty of:

$\frac{4}{5^4} * 4 = \frac{16}{625} $

But my result is incorrect and must be $\frac{16}{125}$, what is incorrect in my thought?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer is correct if you read the problem as requiring exactly $3$ wins.  If, as I would, you read it as requiring at least $3$ wins then you have to add $\frac 1{625}$ to cover the case $WWWW$.  I don't see where the official answer comes from.

Comment: The possible answer are: $a)1/125$,$ b) 16/125$, $ c) 96/625$, $d) 256/625$ , $e) 2/256$ and according to the guide is $b)$

Comment: Well, as I say, I think the answer is $\frac {17}{625}$ though I understand your answer too.  Is it possible we are misinterpreting the question?  I am guessing, for instance, that a "draw" is the same as a "game" but perhaps that is not the case.